# mongodb aggregate and group with push

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to push the data who is having minSalary using $push at group aggregate.

Query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { experience: { $gte:3, $lte:10} } },
    { $group: { _id: {totalExperience:"$experience"}, "count": {$sum:1},"minSalary": {$min:"$expected_salary"}, "minUsers": {$push:"$_id"}, "maxSalary": {$max:"$expected_salary"} } },    
    { $sort: { '_id.totalExperience': -1 } }    
])
```

Result

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "totalExperience" : 9
    },
    "count" : 549.0,
    "minSalaryCount" : 120000,
    "maxSalary" : 180000
}
```

Also i am expecting following result

```
  {
    "_id" : {
        "totalExperience" : 9
    },
    "count" : 549.0,
    "minSalaryCount" : 120000,
    "maxSalary" : 180000,
    "minSalaryUsers":[
       ObjectId('5355345345sdrrw234234'),
       ObjectId('5355345345sdeee234234'),
       ObjectId('5355345345sdertw234234')
    ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to change `$group` to push user ids along with their salaries followed by `$project` stage to  `$filter` the user salaries array on min salary and `$map` the user ids.

Comment: @Veeram Can you me the sample for this?